# BubbleSort Bash is not sorting

Tags: bash, bubble-sort

My bubble sort code in bash script does not swap nor sort. Help me out on what I am doing wrong.

```
echo "Enter numbers  between 4 and 12"
read n
#declare -a numArray  #declare array of numbers
if [ $n -le 12 -a $n -ge 4 ]
then
        #take input from user
        echo "Enter numbers of array"
        for (( i = 0; i < $n; i++ ))
        do
                read numArray[$i]

        done

        #sorting logic
        for (( i = 0; i < $n; i++ ))
        do
                for (( j = 0; j < $n-1; j++ ))
                do
                        # swapping logic
                        #read numArray[$j]

                        if [[ ${numArray[j]} -gt ${numArray[$((j+1))]} ]]
                        then
                                #echo "in swapping code"
                                temp=${numArray[j]}
                                echo $temp
                                numArray[$j]=${numArray[$((j+1))]}
                                numArray[$((j+1))]=$temp
                        fi
                done
        done
        # print sorted data 
        echo -e "\nSorted Numbers "
    echo "${numArray[*]}"
else
echo "Please enter only values between 4 and 12"
fi
```

Result:

```
Enter numbers  between 4 and 12
5
Enter numbers of array
51428

51428
51428
51428
51428

Sorted Numbers 
 51428
```

Comment: I suggest you use `bash -x scriptname`. This will help in debugging

Comment: why enter 5 of the same number `51428`? or did you mean to enter `5` (<return>) `1` (<return>) `4` (<return>) `2` (<return>) `8` (<return>)

Comment: You appear to have just entered a single 5-digit number, rather than 5 numbers. You need to enter each number on a separate line.